# BIgQuery - No matching signature for function ARRAY_TO_STRING

Tags: javascript, sql, google-apps-script, google-bigquery

After running below query

```
           SELECT ARRAY_TO_STRING( reporteeNames, '|') FROM 
         `appsflow-dev.PersonRequisition.ExternalNewHire`;
```

I am getting error

[image: error]

Schema

```
Fieldname                           Type    Mode

reporteeNames                       RECORD  REPEATED    
reporteeNames.reporteeTitle         STRING  NULLABLE    
reporteeNames.reporteeName          RECORD  NULLABLE    
reporteeNames.reporteeName.display  STRING  NULLABLE    
reporteeNames.reporteeName.value    STRING  NULLABLE
```

Please advise a solution specific to my schema.

Comment: You probably need to set the flag for using Standard SQL.

Comment: I'm already using Standard SQL. I checked my settings, the SQL Dialect choosen is "Standard".

Comment: @AbhishekBapna - can you clarify what exactly result you are expecting!

Comment: I was expecting the array to be converted into string to be displayed in a cell for each row.
The method given in the answer posted below worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unnest the array in order to select the field inside the struct:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT STRING_AGG(reporteeName, '|')
   FROM UNNEST(reporteeNames)) AS names
FROM `your-project`.dataset.table
```

See also the [working with arrays documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays).